# Differential geometry : crofton formula

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry

So I was reading an article, and it says that if a parametric curve $s(t)$ defined on I has values in a sphere $S^{2}$, the length of $s$, can be deduced by its intersection with great circles using the following formula:
$$\operatorname{length}(s)=\frac{1}{4}\int_{S^{2}}\operatorname{card}\{t \in I/s(t).N=0\}\,\mathrm{d}N$$
Can someone give me an example where he applies the formula on a parametic curve so that I understand how it works and how to apply it.

Comment: Try taking a great circle, a half great circle, and a general line of latitude on the sphere. Understand which great circles intersect each of these examples, and how many times in each case.

Comment: When i try to think about it, I end up with 1/2 , i dont know where the 1/4 is coming from

Comment: Are you doing the entire sphere of unit normal vectors? Each great circle counts twice because of the two orientations.

Comment: No. This is what happens when you leave your proof of proposition 3.2 as an exercise for the reader sir.